# Why doesn't my CountDownTimer is not count?

Tags: android

I have a CountDownTimer in for loop, but it doesn't count. Why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < payloadList.size(); i++) {
                sonpx.dtnsocialnetwork.Bundle bundle = new sonpx.dtnsocialnetwork.Bundle(
                        srcIMEI, desIMEI, fileName, i, totalFragment,
                        numOfSendingRest, payloadList.get(i));
                byte[][] payload = new byte[1][];
                try {
                    payload[0] = serialize(bundle);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "bundle payload size: "+payload[0].length);
                mDefaultChannel.sendData(nodeName, DIRECT_BUNDLE, payload);

                CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 100) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if (bundleResultOk) {
                            cancel();
                            bundleResultOk = false;
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "bundle result: "+bundleResultOk);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        counterFinish = true;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Send Message time out");
                    }
                };
                countDownTimer.start();
}
```

It doesn't print Log.i(TAG, "bundle result: "+bundleResultOk);

Comment: may be payloadList.size() = 0;

Comment: Please help yourself, and learn to use the debugger.  Step through your code to understand what's happening.  Trying to build apps without the debugger is like trying to cut down a forest with a butter knife.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the code in not running in a HandlerThread

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom [CountdownTimer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java)